# How can I generate permutation list and write file

Tags: python, file-io, output, permutation

I've write sentences and wanna combine it together, but in a permutation order.
Each sentence is stored in `outputa1.txt outputa2.txt outputa3.txt` and combined senteces will be stored in outputone.txt.

I've found out a permutation code

```
a=itertools.permutations(["output()","output1()","output2()"],2)
b=str(random.choice(list(a)))
outfile.write(str(b))
```

I believe this code may help me complete the code.

But the problem is, because only output() is including `outfile=open("outputone.txt","w")` code, in def output1(), it cannot cognize the outputone. But if I add `outfile=open("outputone.txt","w")` to all the def, only one sentence came out, not combined.

If I remove def, I can make the code but I lose permutation order.

I know this code and my English skill is very sloppy because I've studied them alone without any books.

Please anyone to improve my python skills.. I would be really appreciate it!!

```
def output() :          
     infile=open("file.txt","r")
     outfile=open("outputone.txt","w")

     line= open('outputa1.txt').readlines()
     line=''.join(line)
     outfile.write("\n")

def output1() :

     line= open('outputa2.txt').readlines()
     line=''.join(line)
     outfile.write(line)
     outfile.write("\n")

def output2() :

     line= open('outputa3.txt').readlines()
     line=''.join(line)
     outfile.write(line)
     outfile.write("\n")

     infile.close()
     outfile.close()

output()
output1()
output2()
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is at this line:

```
outfile=open("outputone.txt","w")
```

you need to open this file in append mode: `outfile=open("outputone.txt","a")`
at function 'output' you miss `outfile.write(line)`

for clarity i would wrote a helper function to append a file to another. when you are working with files with statement is the way to go, more info at: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

```
def append_to(source, output):
    with open(source, 'r') as source_file:
        rows = source_file.readlines()
        s = '\n'.join(rows)

    with open(output, 'a') as output_file:
        output_file.write(s)
```

Comment: OH  MY GOD you are my savior!!!! I really appreciate thanks a lot !!!!!!!!